# Chrome plugin plugin cannot use fetch to send https requests to local services

Tags: https, fetch

The Chrome plugin uses fetch to send HTTPS requests to local services, with URLs similar to https://10.10.10.10:3000 This format has already been configured with TLS. When using HTTP and turning off TLS, the local service can receive responses. When using HTTP and enabling TLS, bad request this combination of host and port requirements TLS will be returned.
Will browser plugins be restricted from sending requests to local services? If restricted, can relevant documents be provided. If not restricted, what do I need to do?